# Enabling youtube data api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I generated an youtube api key, but when I use it in

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=FH2zbHrRY9A&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

it shows me a warning message like

```
"Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 950908475774 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=950908475774 then retry"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a simple tutorial for this. See [Getting Started](https://python-youtube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

You can follow my tutorial to enable the service.

You need to enable this api service before you use the YouTube DATA API.

[image]